# Couldn't load OpenSSL library in 12.1 (Windows)

Tags: windows, librarylink, cryptography, version-12.1

**Update**:
Finally I found a clumsy way to solve this bug by myself: I created an alternate **local** kernel to run the code, and it surprisingly works out!

[image: Alternating Local Kernel]

It is ridiculous that two local kernels contain different features/bugs, I still cannot figure out the reason...

---

Recently when I evaluate

```
$Version
GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[]
```

on Windows10 1909 with Mathematica 12.1 in the front-end, it warns me:

```
"12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)"
Encrypt::libopenssl: Couldn't load OpenSSL library.
$Failed
```

However, **it works perfectly in the Wolfram Kernel 12.1 without errors**. And everything is fine on a Linux machine of version 12.1,  as well as the Windows in the front-end of version 12.0. Does anybody encounter the same problem with me?

---

I tried to dig more about the issue, the corresponding OpenSSL file lies in

```
$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\Components\Cryptography\OpenSSLLink.m
```

or from the paclet

```
$UserBasePacletsDirectory\Repository\Cryptography-12.2.0\OpenSSLLink.m
```

The warning comes from the command

```
checkedLibraryFunctionLoad[libraryPath, "scrypt", 
{{Integer, 1}, {Integer, 1}, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer}, {Integer, 1}]
```

with

```
LibraryFunction::libload: The function scrypt was not loaded from the file $UserBasePacletsDirectory\Repository\Cryptography-12.2.0\Resources\Libraries\OpenSSLLink64.dll.
```

While the file `OpenSSLLink64.dll` already exists, I am not familiar with `LibraryFunctionLoad`, I hope someone can help me fix this problem.

---

Then I follow [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)'s suggestion to evaluate `` LibraryLink`$LibraryError `` and obtain the output: `Library load error 127: 找不到指定的程序。` (The specified module could not be found). Although my Windows Language is Chinese, all the installed paths (including the user name) are in English.

[image: Error Notifications]

Comment: I installed 12.1 version of Mathematica on win10. I didn't get the error you said after running your code.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. *Do* add this tag to other people's questions when appropriate. Please see the tag description for more details.

Comment: Can you reproduce this after restarting Mathematica? If yes, please evaluate ``LibraryLink`$LibraryError`` immediately after the error and add the result to the question.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for you reply, I have removed the tag and updated the question.

Comment: It might be a bug ... @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes Do you have the same version of that paclet? What does `PacletObject["Cryptography"]["Version"]` say? I can't test on WIndows.

Comment: @Pei-XinShen What if you re-install that paclet? `PacletUninstall["Cryptography"]` then restart the kernel, then do `PacletInstall["Cryptography", UpdatePacletSites -> True]`, then restart again, then try again

Comment: If this does not resolve the problem, it might be a good idea to contact Wolfram Support ...

Comment: @Szabolcs My "Cryptography" version is "12.2.0", I have reinstall it many times (even reinstall the whole Mathematica) and it doesn't work... Yeah, I will contact Wolfram support, thanks for your help :)

Comment: For what it worth, I'm on same Windows and Mathematica versions as OP, but I haven't been able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Pei-XinShen Can you check the value of `Environment["PATH"]` and compare it between a working and a non-working 12.1 kernel? Are they the same or are they different?

Comment: @Szabolcs Nope, they are the same. To compare them strictly, I copy them to run `==` and return `True`.

Comment: See my comment under the other [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/218761/145). We should have a fix for this in the form of a paclet update soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A likely fix for this issue has been released with the CURLLink 12.1.1 paclet update.

This update will not be automatically installed, but can be acquired by evaluating

```
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[];
PacletInstall["CURLLink"]
```

and restarting Mathematica.

---

If anyone is curious, here are some comments on the symptoms being observed.

As mentioned in the question, there was an error in loading the library function `scrypt`:

> `LibraryFunction::libload`:
>
> The function `scrypt` was not loaded from the file ... `OpenSSLLink64.dll`.

There is nothing special about that symbol, it just happens to be the first one attempted.

Furthermore, it is not missing from `OpenSSLLink64.dll` and the latter library is not corrupt in any way, but it does fail to load, so none of its symbols can be found.

The problem is not with `OpenSSLLink64.dll` but with its main dependency, the OpenSSL library `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`.

Normally it would be dynamically loaded from the Mathematica layout, specifically from the `SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64` directory and everything would work correctly.

But under certain circumstances, another instance of the library present on the system (most likely installed in a system-wide location like `C:\Windows\System32`) can be found under the standard Windows [DLL search order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

It is also likely to be incompatible with OpenSSLLink because it has been compiled with a different set of enabled features, which results in the error seen.

This will not be the case for most Windows installations (and clearly it was not the case for any of the systems used in release testing).

What is the relevance of CURLLink and how can updating that paclet fix the problem? It turns out that one of `libcurl`'s several dependencies can indirectly load `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` by relying on the OS to locate it.

This happens early in the session, especially when the FE is used, for purposes such as checking for paclet updates or signing in to the cloud.

By the way, that also explains the differences seen in a standalone kernel, or in an alternative local kernel, which happen to be initialized in a slightly different way.

Fortunately, this problem is easy to fix by explicitly preloading the above dynamic dependency from its correct location instead of asking the OS for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have checked this bug is perfectly fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I expanded the answer with some more details.

Answer (score 2):

The error message

```
LibraryFunction::libload: The function scrypt was not loaded from the file C:\Users\[MYNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\Cryptography-12.2.0\Resources\Libraries\OpenSSLLink64.dll.
```

suggests that the library downloaded to your `$UserBasePacletsDirectory` is corrupt in some manner.

I would recommend running `SystemOpen@$UserBasePacletsDirectory`, going to the `/Repository/` subdirectory, and deleting all directories that start with `Cryptography`. Restart Mathematica, try the functionality again, and see what happens. Hopefully it will work.

I've checked the .dll within the same paclet installed on my Windows machine and it doesn't seem to have this issue the `scrypt` symbol *is* present.

If the above does not work, alternatively you can copy `OpenSSLLink64.dll` from `$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\Components\Cryptography\Resources\Libraries` to your `C:\Users\[MYNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\Cryptography-12.2.0\Resources\Libraries\`. Barring any sort of corruption, the .dll at both of these locations should be near identical in content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) The first suggestion does not work, and I have checked the two `OpenSSLLink64.dll` are exactly the same. Besides I tried to run `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[]` directly in the Kernel and found surprisingly no errors !!! While evaluating in the front-end fails, which makes me very puzzled.

Comment: @Pei-XinShen what does `Cryptography\`$LibraryVersion` return in both your FE and kernel?

Comment: The front-end still returns `Encrypt::libopenssl: Couldn't load OpenSSL library. $Failed`, while the kernel gives `OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019`. I also try `PacletObject["Cryptography"]["Version"]`, and they both returns `12.2.0.` @ktm

Comment: What if you try loading the libraries directly: `LibraryLoad[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Libraries", $SystemID, "libcrypto-1_1-x64"}]]; path = LibraryLoad[ToFileName[PacletManager\`PacletResource["Cryptography", "Libraries"], "OpenSSLLink64.dll"]]; LibraryFunctionLoad[path, "generateRSAKey", {"UTF8String", Integer, Integer}, {Integer, 1}]`. If that fails, what is `LibraryLink\`$LibraryError`?

Comment: For the default local Kernel, it fails and returns `Library load error 127`, as  illustrated in the question. But it is weird that when I create another local kernel, everything runs perfectly there (shown in my updated figure).

Comment: The "missing procedure" that error 127 refers to is not `scrypt` but something else. And while OpenSSLLink64.dll fails to load, the problem isn't in the DLL itself.