# Windows error after Installation Mathematica 12.1

Tags: windows, installation

I have not been able to resolve the same issue as cited in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218670/couldnt-load-openssl-library-in-12-1-windows).

I receive this error:
[image]

I have uninstalled. Installed previous version: which has no error. Uninstalled and reinstalled.

I have contacted Technical Support but have not had satisfactory resolution.
 I would value help in this regard.

Comment: It is possible there is some copy of libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll on your system that is being used instead of the correct one in the 12.1 layout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Couldn't load OpenSSL library in 12.1 (Windows)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218670/couldnt-load-openssl-library-in-12-1-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A likely fix for this issue has been released with the CURLLink 12.1.1 paclet update.

This update will not be automatically installed, but can be acquired by evaluating

```
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[];
PacletInstall["CURLLink"]
```

and restarting Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you @ilian I will try when I get a chance.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to have resolved the matter.

Comment: Glad to hear it and thank you for the confirmation. In this case I think this question can be merged with the earlier one.